# NHibernate and Interceptor in aggregate root

Tags: c#, nhibernate, interceptor, aggregateroot

Assuming that object A has a list of B objects, and B is linked to a C one.

Using NHibernate, if I update as C instance, how can I be notified that "something" linked to one instance (and which instance) of A has been updated ?

Using interceptor I know that C has been updated, but how to follow the way C -> B -> A automatically (C doesn't know B for instance, and C is not always aggregate root).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the specifics of your mapping, you can always search for the linked `B` entities every time an entity `C` is modified. Given that `B` is related to `C` by a foreign key relationship, you can search for all `B` (or the single `B`), which has a foreign key equal to the `C` entity primary key.

If at the same time `B` does not know about `A`, you can use a similar procedure to notify which instance of `A` it is related to. Or, if in the other hand `B` has a link to `A`, you can use that relationship instead.

The specific implementation would depend on how exactly are you mapping these entities together.

Comment: You mean to create NH interceptor and when updated entity is of type `C`, execute query or navigate through relationships to find `B` then `A`?

Comment: If you have no relationship established from `C` to `B`, or from `B` to `A`, then yes.